# Line to Line intersection in Clipper

Tags: c++, clipperlib, clipper

**Does the clipper has a line to line interSection or not?**

This is the Code I have tried and I don't get any point that is intersecting

```
_line1 = (10,10) (10,20)//Given Input
_line2 = (10,10) (10,20)//Given Input

Clipper clipperObj;
PolyTree _point;
clipperObj.AddPath(_line1, ptSubject, false);
clipperObj.AddPath(_line2, ptSubject, false);
clipperObj.Execute(ctIntersection, _point);
clipperObj.Clear();
```

Comment: Your lines are co-linear, aren't they? (Identical, to be precise.) Would you count this as no intersection or infinite number of intersections? Have you tried other values where you know the result for?

Comment: Answer: no.The clip paths must be closed. See http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper/documentation/Docs/Units/ClipperLib/Classes/ClipperBase/Methods/AddPath.htm